# Backbone.js Model defaults and parse

Tags: backbone.js

I've got this `Backbone.Model` representing a Google Books API volume:

```
    var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        volumeInfo : {
            title: 'n.a.',
            authors: 'n.a.',
            publisher: 'n.a.',
            publishedDate: 'n.a.',
            imageLinks : {
                smallThumbnail: '/unavailable.jpg'
            }
        }
    },

    parse: function(resp) {
        if (resp.volumeInfo.authors) {
            resp.volumeInfo.authors = resp.volumeInfo.authors.join(',');
        }
        return resp;
    }
});
```

Which is fed to this template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="bookCollectionRow">
    <tr>
        <td><img class="thumbnail" src="<%= volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail %>" /></td>
        <td><a target="_blank" href="<%= volumeInfo.canonicalVolumeLink %>"><%= volumeInfo.title %></a></td>
        <td><%= volumeInfo.authors %></td>
        <td><%= volumeInfo.publisher %></td>
        <td><%= volumeInfo.publishedDate %></td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Upon parsing the template, when a volume JSON does not contain an `imageLinks` I receive this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'smallThumbnail' of undefined.
```

I know I could fix it by checking with an `if` in the `Model` or in the `template` but what's the purpose of `defaults` model property then? Does that work only if not overriding `parse`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A few things. First, you shouldn't have nested objects as backbone model attributes in general - it can be OK if you can always treat the attribute atomically, but this is a perfect example of when you can't. From a data-model perspective, imageLinks should be its *own* backbone model class, as should volumeInfo.

Second, if defaults is an object literal (`{}`) instead of a function, the same object is used as the default attrs for each model instance. I think you want this:

```
defaults: function(){
    return {
        volumeInfo : {} // should be new VolumeInfo({}) imo
    };
},
```

But the data model is the bigger issue - .defaults doesn't do the kind of nested-object-template thing you seem to be going for, and for good reason: it doesn't work well, this will just be the first of many gotchas you'll run into if you don't keep your instance data pretty flat.

Comment: I don't agree with your first paragraph here. Using another model just for what is just a sub-object is overkill, and makes things like getting data verbatim from the Google API much more difficult

Comment: I'm still trying to learn Backbone but from what you say, it doesn't seem a good solution to work with most of the webservices out there :/ As to `defaults` as an object literal, I was following this tutorial: http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-model/ is that wrong then?

Comment: Except this isn't a sub-object: it's related model that has state, or behavior, or something - it's a *thing*, and it's in charge of thumbnail urls. Trying to map data verbatim from external APIs into your data types doesn't seem like a good idea either. In fact, that's really why a parse method exists: Google's choices around how to structure their data may or may not be the same as yours, and if not, parse is where to do the conversion. Setting a template object tree that gets partially merged from external data is... edge-case prone to say the least.

Comment: The tutorial example uses native javascript literals as defaults: id 1, name "Thomas", etc. In that case, it's fine to not use a function for defaults. But you have a container type as the value of one of your defaults; you're sharing the same volumeInfo object for all instances that don't have it in attrs when instantiated. Sharing name:"Thomas" isn't an issue, because you can't mutate "Thomas", only set a new string. You *can* mutate volumeInfo['title'], without realizing that it's the same volumeInfo for all instances that didn't have it set explicitly.