# Nested properties in Backbone model altering defaults object

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Backbone's model instance ( which includes nested param) changes are affecting Model's defaults.

```
X = Backbone.Model.extend({defaults:{x:{y:{z:1}}, a: "hello"}})

x = (new X()).toJSON()

/*
x -- defaults -->
{
  "x": {
    "y": {
      "z": 1
    }
  },
  "a": "hello"
}
*/

// using lodash's merge, update nested object value
_.merge(x,{x:{y:{z:2}},a:"world"})

/*
{
  "x": {
    "y": {
      "z": 2 // nested, changed
    }
  },
  "a":"world" // changed
}
*/

y = (new X()).toJSON()

/*
y, should be defaults -->
{
  "x": {
    "y": {
      "z": 2 //What!!
    }
  },
  "a":"hello" // remains same as default
}
*/
```

The default's obj's nested param's references are getting updated -- hence, all following models created will have the new reference ( created via new, hence default's object ).

Was trying to find a way to resolve this without making the nested object as another model.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17775917/6999988 ?

Comment: Executive summary: `defaults` are shallow copied, use a function if there's anything mutable in your `defaults`.